# How to test com object registration?

Tags: c#, com, .net-assembly

I have created a C# class library and registered as com object successfully. and i tried to check that by creating a console application and tried to add the reference from the com tab, i could not get the registered com object from there. can any one check how can i test whether the com object registered successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you register a COM dll with regsvr32 a record is added to the registry. You need to check if that entry is there or not.

Comment: I used RegAsm.exe /codebase to regiter my assembly, i got "type registered successfully" message. where to check in registry?

Comment: Under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\ or HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\

Comment: inside \classes , is there any folder ? because i dont see my dll under the classes